# Getting DataKeyNames for row on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with buttons in each row:

[image]

The buttons are in a templatefield:

```
<asp:GridView ID="storyGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"    
      CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="PK_NonScrumStory" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="viewHoursButton" runat="server" Text="View Hours" OnClick="viewHoursButton_OnClick" />
                <asp:Button ID="addHoursButton" runat="server" Text="Add Hours" OnClick="addHoursButton_OnClick" />
                <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="editButton_OnClick" />
                <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="deleteButton_OnClick" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

How do I get the data key name on click?

```
protected void viewHoursButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get PK_NonScrumStory for clicked row
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
protected void viewHoursButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string pk = storyGridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pk);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can bind `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` for your custom **Buttons**, for exemple:

```
<asp:Button ID="deleteButton" 
 runat="server" 
 Text="Delete" 
 CommandName="DeleteItem" 
 CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
 OnClick="deleteButton_OnClick" />
```

Then you should impletement the event storyGridView1_RowCommand, and treat every command:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "DeleteItem")
  {
    // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
    // CommandArgument property.
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
    // from the Rows collection.
     GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

    //Retrieve the key of the row and delete the item

  }
  else if(e.CommandName == "EditItem")
  {
    //edit the item
  }
  //Other commands
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong event.  Use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

GridView.RowCommand - it's an event on the Grid, not on the cell.  On the cell, you provide CommandName string = so instead of your OnClick event, you'd have CommandName="ViewHours".

Then in your myGridView_RowCommand event handler you get one of these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx

and you put in a big switch statement on e.CommandName.  Ugly, but it works.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

that gets you your Row Index.  You can use it with myGridView.DataKeys[index] to fetch DataKeys.

...

Yeah, I know.