# Update Access Database (.mdb) using GridView where ID column is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, gridview

I want to read and store the DataKeyNames value for the corresponding row that is selected from the GridView so that I can pass that value as a condition in my UPDATE query.

I have a GridView in which I am displaying the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSavingsTracker" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
OnRowCommand="GridViewSavingsTracker_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="creditorName" HeaderText="Creditor Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Principal Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="interestRate" HeaderText="Interest Rate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="interestType" HeaderText="Interest Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="interestCalculationMethod" HeaderText="Interest Calculation Method" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My database has an ID field that I am not displaying on the GridView.

When I click the button, I should be able to update the selected row in the GridView where; the WHERE clause of the UPDATE SQL command has to be the ID of the row that is selected. This ID is stored in the database and is not visible in the GridView. So, the corresponding ID value has to be read from the database.

My Button Click event is the following:

```
protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE table_name SET employeeName = '" +TextBoxEmployeeName.Text+"' WHERE ID=...<The ID value that will be read from the Database has to come here>...";
        OleDBCommand updateCommand = new OleDBCommand(updateQuery,con);
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        ShowGrid();    // Method to populate and display the GridView on the screen. 
    }
```

I am populating the TextBoxes using the RowCommand where I am reading the rowID in the following manner:

```
protected void GridViewSavingsTracker_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        }
    }
```

In a nutshell, I need to read the ID value from the MS Access Database (where the ID is a column in my database and each tuple has a unique ID value) when a particular row is selected in the GridView. This has to be done when I click the "Update" button on the web page. Once I am able to do that, then I will be able to put that value in the SQL command in the code and do the update.

I am trying to do what David mentioned in his answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824029/8930129

But "row" is getting a null value, because of which I am getting an System.NullReferenceException.

```
// ****Update Command **** //
protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {    
        int rowIndex = GridViewSavingsTracker.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
        int tupleID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSavingsTracker.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
        con.Open();
        string ConnString = GetConnString();
        string updateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_savings SET creditorName = ?, amount = ?, interestRate = ?, interestType = ?, interestCalculationMethod = ? WHERE ID=" + tupleID + "";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand commandUpdate = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, conn))
            {
                commandUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                commandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("creditorName", TextBoxCreditorName.Text);
                commandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("amount", TextBoxPrincipalAmount.Text);
                commandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("interestRate", TextBoxInterestRate.Text);
                commandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("interestType", RadioButtonListInterestType.SelectedValue);
                commandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("interestCalculationMethod",DropDownListInterestCalculationMethod.SelectedValue);
            }
        }
        OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con);
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        ShowGridView();    // Function to populate data in GridView
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        // Some code...
    }
    finally
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work in the following way:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE " + table_name + " SET creditorName = ?, amount = ?, interestRate = ?, ... WHERE savingsID = ?";
                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con))
    {
        updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("creditorName", TextBoxCreditorName.Text);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("amount", TextBoxPrincipalAmount.Text);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("interestRate", TextBoxInterestRate.Text);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("savingsID", tupleID);

        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

and I am getting the value of `tupleID` in the following way:

```
int tupleID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
```

Source: Comments from @Matt-9000 and https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are quite going about it the right way. You want to use the gridview row number to lookup the database ID so that you can use that database ID to update the row in the database?

You should be able to store the IDs as part of the GridView, even if you aren't displaying them.

Check out the DataKeyNames property of a GridView. It allows you to specify the primary key fields of your object.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can access the IDs on postback events, check out this example:

- https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DataKeyNames-in-GridView-example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got the following from the link you shared: 

protected void GridView_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Determine the RowIndex of the Row whose Button was clicked.
    int rowIndex = ((sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;
 
    //Get the value of column from the DataKeys using the RowIndex.
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
}

IDE is prompting me an error at the first line. Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to 'Int'.

Comment: What you mentioned is exactly what I need. I might not have been able to express my requirement properly. I want to read and store the DataKeyNames value for the corresponding row that is selected from the GridView so that I can pass that value as a condition in my UPDATE query.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work? I'm not sure what your configuration is exactly since I can't see all of your code. When you are firing the button click, you should be able to lookup the ID similar to this `Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);` once you get the selected rowIndex.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly advise against using string concatenation to create your Update command in order to prevent SQL injection. Check out using [parameters with your command](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice. I will keep that in mind. The row did get updated, but not how I wanted it. The data in the first column is automatically getting replaced as -1. For example, my first column is fName. So, for a tuple, if the firstName is "Mark", then upon updating, the firstName is becomming "-1" even if I don't update the text in the firstName TextBox.

Comment: I can’t really determine what’s going on there without seeing your updated SQL code.

Comment: con.Open();
int rowIndex = GridViewSavingsTracker.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
int tupleID=Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSavingsTracker.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
// Qurey comes here. I have posted the query in the next comment. 
updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

Comment: string updateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_savings SET creditorName = '" + TextBoxCreditorName.Text + "' and amount = '" + TextBoxPrincipalAmount.Text + "' and interestRate='" + TextBoxInterestRate.Text + "' and interestType='" + RadioButtonListInterestType.SelectedValue + "' and interestCalculationMethod='" + DropDownListInterestCalculationMethod.SelectedValue + "' WHERE ID = " + tupleID + "";
OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con);

Comment: At the same time, I would like to update using the same TextBox. As in, then I click the select button located in front of the row that I want to update, the data from that table gets filled into the corresponding TextBoxes, RadioButtonLists, and DropDownBoxes. This is the data that I want to update. So, I modify the contents in the same TextBox in which they were displayed and then press Update Button. By clicking the button, the modified data should get read and updated to the database.

Comment: I believe the values should be comma separated in your update statement, and not have an `and` in between them. And you should be able to update the text boxes with the selected values in row command event.

Comment: Guess what! That seems to have worked. So, the UPDATE query is correct but I am still not able to change a particular field to new value. 
What I want to do is now that I have 1 TextBox and 1 Button. The old misspelled data is there in that TextBox with the help of the select CommandButton on the GridView. I will correct the spelling using my keyboad  and press Update button on the screen. This should replace the old value with the new value in the database. 
This was a simple example. I want to do the same for 3 TextBoxes, 1 DropDownList and 1 RadioButtonList when I click the Update Button

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. Not sure I follow what you are asking now. You should be able to update all of those fields in the same SQL statement by grabbing the new values from all of the input fields.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I have 3 TextBoxes, 1 DropDownList, and 1 RadioButtonList. I have two buttons - Select and Update. Select button is there in front of each row in the GridView. If the user wants to update certain info in a row, he will click on the corresponding select button and the data from the corresponding row will get filled in the fields accordingly. Then he corrects/changes the information and clicks update. The update button updates the information in the database. I hope that clears things.

Comment: Matt, I seem to have found a way to solve the problem. I just need to correct the following error that I am getting: 

"No value given for one or more required parameters."

My query is: 

string updateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_savings SET creditorName = ?, amount = ?, interestRate = ?, interestType = ?, interestCalculationMethod = ? WHERE ID=" + tupleID + "";

Comment: Matt, see the last (3rd) code snippet that I have posted in the question on top. That should give you a clearer picture of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, that’s looks good. Good to see you have switched to using parameters with your update statement.

Comment: Upon using the above mentioned code, I am getting the following error: 

No value given for one or more required parameters.

The comment points to the line...

updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You are executing updateCommand which is a new command that was just created. You need to execute commandUpdate which has all of your parameters. You will need to do that inside the using scope of commandUpdate.